# How to separate yew components to different files?

Tags: rust, frontend, webassembly, rust-wasm, yew

I just started learning yew (frontend framework). How do i put every component in separate file, like in js frameworks. (i am using function components now)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a file like `src/components/text.rs`, create a file called components.rs, and include the module like so:

`pub mod Text;`

Then, in main.rs, you can `mod components;` allowing you to use Text elsewhere in your project with something like:

`use crate::components::text::Text`

Comment: A good example project that does this: https://github.com/yewstack/yew/tree/yew-v0.19.3/examples/function_todomvc